# Google Maps API - Get info window to open when clicking a circle?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geometry, infowindow

I'm trying desparately to get a google map with circles which can be clicked to open an infowindow. It really doesn't seem like a complicated ask but searching online it does't seem to be possible, but I'm wondering if those posts are old and it's now possible.

**What I'm trying to do**
I'm trying to have a google map (HTML code which I can 'host' on SharePoint) with circles in different locations (This bit is fine so far) where I can click the circle to open an info window with a list of people at that location.

**What I've done so far**
I've been looking at the google maps javascript API pages and successfully made a map with circles using this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple

I've also tried putting a marker at the centre of the map with an infowindow which is less than ideal but still acceptable, however this didn't work. I literaly just cut the part of the javascript which does a marker and the page wouldn't load.

**My Background** Unfortunately I have no idea about Javascript. I know a little about HTML but I'm certainly not from a technical background, I just want a map which looks nice and works. I could literally be one character from making it work but I've no clue what javascript means. .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Newsletter Map</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
// This example creates circles on the map, representing
// populations in North America.

// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
var citymap = {};
citymap['Mumbai'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.075787,72.8774882),
  population: 14000
};
citymap['Cardiff'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4887969,-3.1826222),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Pune'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.5212252,73.8556156),
  population: 14000
};
citymap['Beeston'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.9547839,-1.1581733),
  population: 3000
};
citymap['Birmingham'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.4677785,-1.7230922),
  population: 4000
};
citymap['Bristol'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5434779,-2.573748),
  population: 2000
};
citymap['Brussels'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8891268,4.4592719),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Crewe'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.0888925,-2.4357559),
  population: 2000
};
citymap['Dundee'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4563534,-2.9752489),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Durham'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.5468172,-1.5703596),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Glasgow'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.8601948,-4.256542),
  population: 2000
};
citymap['Liverpool'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4114691,-2.9954281),
  population: 5000
};
citymap['Livingston'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.8889266,-3.5575676),
  population: 12000
};
citymap['Moray'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.6153854,-3.5727702),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Newcastle'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.0114826,-1.6218245),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Runcorn'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3416269,-2.7312661),
  population: 6000
};
citymap['Winnersh'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.43674,-0.89131),
  population: 5000
};
citymap['Wolverhampton'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6375302,-2.1184067),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Plymouth'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.3752499,-4.1425974),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Swinton Manch'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5108841,-2.3468262),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Cleveleys'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.8758639,-3.0423774),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Peterborough'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5694182,-0.2415024),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Saffron Walden'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.0224437,0.2393275),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Gloucester'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.864033,-2.2382369),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['LTQ'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5250213,-0.141524),
  population: 18000
};
citymap['Enfield'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.651765,-0.0835785),
  population: 1000
};

var cityCircle;

function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3789721,-1.4693043),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  }
}


 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">FQNCM6NFZFN7-2543-7</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">a9ec8002-9354-4aef-9bbe-aac4a1d8f794</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">https://sp.myatos.net/ms/uki/bs/bo/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=FQNCM6NFZFN7-2543-7, FQNCM6NFZFN7-2543-7</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no infowindow in your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an infowindow: `var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();`
2. set its content, position and open it on a click:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function(e) {
     infowindow.setContent(this.getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + this.getRadius());
     infowindow.setPosition(this.getCenter());
     infowindow.open(map);
   });
   ```

working code snippet:

```js
// This example creates circles on the map, representing
// populations in North America.

// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
var citymap = {};
citymap['Mumbai'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.075787, 72.8774882),
  population: 14000
};
citymap['Cardiff'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4887969, -3.1826222),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Pune'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.5212252, 73.8556156),
  population: 14000
};
citymap['Beeston'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.9547839, -1.1581733),
  population: 3000
};
citymap['Birmingham'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.4677785, -1.7230922),
  population: 4000
};
citymap['Bristol'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5434779, -2.573748),
  population: 2000
};
citymap['Brussels'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.8891268, 4.4592719),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Crewe'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.0888925, -2.4357559),
  population: 2000
};
citymap['Dundee'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4563534, -2.9752489),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Durham'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.5468172, -1.5703596),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Glasgow'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.8601948, -4.256542),
  population: 2000
};
citymap['Liverpool'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4114691, -2.9954281),
  population: 5000
};
citymap['Livingston'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.8889266, -3.5575676),
  population: 12000
};
citymap['Moray'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(57.6153854, -3.5727702),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Newcastle'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.0114826, -1.6218245),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Runcorn'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3416269, -2.7312661),
  population: 6000
};
citymap['Winnersh'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.43674, -0.89131),
  population: 5000
};
citymap['Wolverhampton'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6375302, -2.1184067),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Plymouth'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.3752499, -4.1425974),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Swinton Manch'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5108841, -2.3468262),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Cleveleys'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.8758639, -3.0423774),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Peterborough'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5694182, -0.2415024),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Saffron Walden'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.0224437, 0.2393275),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['Gloucester'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.864033, -2.2382369),
  population: 1000
};
citymap['LTQ'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5250213, -0.141524),
  population: 18000
};
citymap['Enfield'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.651765, -0.0835785),
  population: 1000
};

var cityCircle;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3789721, -1.4693043),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  
  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function(e) {
      infowindow.setContent(this.getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + this.getRadius());
      infowindow.setPosition(this.getCenter());
      infowindow.open(map);
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: That's  brilliant, I'm just wondering how I can add some text for each city point to put in the infowindow? I'm guessing it's to do with changing infowindow.setContent(this.getCenter().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + this.getRadius()); 
in order to get the information from another source, like a bit of code under the citymap for point. How would I write this? Could you give me an example?

Thanks

Comment: Sure you can.  However, there is/was no attempt in your posted code to do that.  And adding that at this point changes the question.

Comment: The code was what I had so far which was simply circles on a map as I didn't know how to do the infowindow. I did mention in the question that I was hoping to make it where I can click the circle to open an info window with a list of people at that location.

Comment: I can't share the list as it's confidential names.
Under 
citymap['Cardiff'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4887969, -3.1826222),
  population: 1000
};
Population, can I add Names: (zyx, abc) and then in the infowindow.setContent(this.getCenter().toUrlValue(6) part reference that piece of data? What's the syntax I would need to use to do this?